# Coding AntiVirus using signatures-based technique

Tags: c++, database, algorithm, winapi, antivirus

I want to code an AntiVirus for learning purposes. It will be signatures-based. I already wrote a scanner that loops through all system files and creats memory mapping for each file. What i am trying to do now, is to get a binary signature (in hex) from each malicious file (sample files) so i can compare it with the database i created.
What is the problem now?
I noticed that the commercial AntiViruses like Kaspersky for example, chooses a file signature from wherever location inside the binary file.
Now suppose that i detected a new malicious file and i chose the offset 0x8766 which has the value 0x4F as a signature for that malicious file. 
now if i want to check a file which has a samll size where the offset 0x8766 does not exist in that small file .. this will be a problem?!
this is sample code represents the way i am going:

```
hFile = ::CreateFile(State.Path, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
                                 0, OPEN_EXISTING,FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN, 0);//open the file

if(hFile !=INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE){
hMap= ::CreateFileMapping(hFile, 0, PAGE_READONLY | SEC_COMMIT, 0, 0, 0);//create Mem mapping for the file in virtual memory
if( hMap!=NULL){
base = ::MapViewOfFile(hMap, FILE_MAP_READ, 0, 0, 0);//load the mapped file into the RAM
//start to compare some bytes (values) from mspaint.exe file in Win7
if( *((BYTE *)base + 0x1C3DF0)== 0x05 )
i++; 
if( *((BYTE *)base + 0x25250C)== 0x21 )
i++;
if( *((BYTE *)base + 0x25272A)== 0x97 )
i++;

if(i==3){
// the file is malicious
}
```

Another question: Do i need to map the whole signatures database in the ram before i start comparing and how? 
and what you suggest signature needs to contain? the file size ...etc? any other suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Signatures generally ain't too big, and you can search them like [this](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/120279-signature-search/). However, keep in mind that if you get hundreds upon thousands of signatures (or more), it becomes unrealistic to re-start check for different signatures on each individual file. You could say that there are levels of each signature used by heuristics to decide whether or not to do next level checking to confirm or deny the match.

These signatures will be quite complex, i.e. describing type of infected file, possible offset locations and so on, thus going a hierarchical (or filtered) approach to arrive to definitive conlcusion.